# Git filter-branch: keep only commits in subdir

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

How can I edit the history of a branch to keep only commits (and part of commits) that affect a specific sub-directory, from a range of commits?

Basically, I have one big repo with some subdirectories that are fairly, but not entirely, independent. In the past, these have been separate repositories, but this turned out to be problematic, so we merged them into 1 repo. This is fine usually, but after a week of hacking at RoboCup, we want to split up 1 big branch into several smaller ones for easier reviewing and separate pull requests.

I have the subdir `challenge_gpsr` on branch `robocup` that I want to create a separate branch for. `robocup` is branched from `189bd987` and because I'm currently on branch `robocup`, `HEAD` points to the final commit in that branch.

Running

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached -qr -- . && git reset -q \$GIT_COMMIT -- challenge_gpsr" --prune-empty -- "robocup" 189bd987..HEAD
```

Leaves only `challenge_gpsr`, but that is not what I want, which is to have the other directories as well, but their state should essentially be that at `189bd987` while the following commits only affect subdir `challenge_gpsr`.

If that works, I repeat this approach for the other subdirs and can review every subdir separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `git filter-branch` before and didn't know it existed so thanks for that :D, but I'm pretty sure I can see what's wrong here...

> Leaves only `challenge_gpsr`, but that is not what I want.

That's what I'd expect from your filter command, have a look at each step:

```
# 1 Remove everything from root-tree (from the new revision)
git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached -qr -- .

# 2 Restore challenge_gpsr sub-tree (from original revision)
git reset -q \$GIT_COMMIT -- challenge_gpsr
```

This runs for each revision between `189bd987..HEAD`, this will result in the first commit after `189bd987` removing everything outside of `challenge_gpsr`, after that all commits will only be modifying objects under `challenge_gpsr`.

> ...have the other directories as well, but their state should essentially be that at `189bd987`

Rather than removing everything, *restore* the whole tree to `189bd987` *then* restore the subtree `challenge_gpsr` from `$GIT_COMMIT`.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter " \
    git reset -q 189bd987 -- . && \
    git reset -q \$GIT_COMMIT -- challenge_gpsr \
" --prune-empty -- "robocup" 189bd987..HEAD
```

Comment: Aha, of course this is the solution. I was close later on but didn't realize I needed to do a reset twice. Thnx!